# Göttsche's formula for non-compact complex surfaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, hilbert-schemes

Is the Göttsche's formula (Eq (2.1) of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304302.pdf)) expressing the Poincare polynomial (or the Euler char version) of the Hilbert scheme of points on a projective surface valid for non-compact complex surfaces? Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is Theorem 5.2.1 of [The Douady space of a complex surface](http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/math/9811159v1.pdf) by de Cataldo and Migliorini (Math.Ann.)